# Как правильно сверстать глаз?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сверстать такой глаз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал использовать border-radius, но что- то не получилось.

```js
const pup = document.querySelector('#pup');
const container = document.querySelector('.lien');

let cursor = {x: 0, y: 0}; 
let position = {x: 0, y: 0};

let width=500, height=500; 
let radius = 20; 
let speedMultiplier = 1e-3; 
let lastTime; 
let frames = 5e5;

function onMouseMove(event){
  const bounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  cursor.x = event.clientX - bounds.left - bounds.width / 2;
  cursor.y = event.clientY - bounds.top - bounds.height / 2;
  cursor.length = Math.sqrt(cursor.x * cursor.x + cursor.y * cursor.y);
  cursor.x *= radius / cursor.length;
  cursor.y *= radius / cursor.length;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

function loop(timestamp) { 
  const deltaTime = lastTime ? timestamp - lastTime : 0;
  lastTime = timestamp;
  if (0 === deltaTime) {
    if (--frames > 0) return requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    else return;
  }

  const multiplier = speedMultiplier * deltaTime;

  const vector = {
    x: cursor.x - position.x,
    y: cursor.y - position.y,
  }; 
 
  position.x += vector.x * multiplier;
  position.y += vector.y * multiplier;
  
  // if(position.x<0) position.x = 0;
  // if(position.x>width-radius*2) position.x = width-radius*2;

  // if(position.y<0) position.y = 0;
  // if(position.y>height-radius*2) position.y = height-radius*2;
  
  pup.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${position.x}, ${position.y})`);
  
  if (--frames > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  else console.log("Out of frames");
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
.conatiner {
  width: 800px;
}

.lien {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="lien anim">
    <svg version="1.1" id="oeil" viewBox="0 0 62 36">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 2;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }

        .st1 {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
      </style>
      <mask id="eyemask">
        <rect fill="black" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="36" />
        <path stroke="black" fill="white" d="M59,18c0,0-12.5,16-28,16S3,18,3,18S15.5,2,31,2S59,18,59,18z" />
      </mask>
      <path id="contour" class="st0 circle" d="M59,18c0,0-12.5,16-28,16S3,18,3,18S15.5,2,31,2S59,18,59,18z" />
      <g mask="url(#eyemask)">
        <g id="pup" class="anim eye">
          <circle class="st1" cx="31" cy="18" r="11" />
          <circle id="rondpup"fill="#FFB703" cx="31" cy="18" r="7" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </a>
   <div class="bottom-line">
     
   </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант SVG

Как-то так:

```js
const pupil = document.getElementById("pup");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;
    const pupilRect = pupil.getBoundingClientRect();
    const radius = 24;
    const angle = Math.atan2(y-pupilRect.top,x-pupilRect.left)+Math.PI;
    pupil.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${-radius*Math.cos(angle)},${-radius*Math.sin(angle)})`);
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="svg4" width="300" height="240" viewBox="0 0 600 480">
 <defs>
 <radialGradient id="Rg" fx="25%" fy="25%">
            <stop offset="10%" stop-color="white" />
            <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FEB703" />
 </radialGradient>
</defs>     
 <g id="pup" class="anim eye" fill="url(#Rg)" > 
  <circle  cx="294" cy="220" r="50"  />
    <circle cx="294" cy="220" r="70" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
  </g>
 <path d="M106.3 193.2s50.5 149 187.6 147.3c135.5-1.7 185-147.3 185-147.3" id="path829" fill="none" 
    stroke="#3B3838" stroke-width="28" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" />
  <path d="M40.3 261.4c73.6-89 158-134.2 253.6-133.8 94 .5 204.8 61.4 248.3 133.8-47.1 75.1-152.3 145.5-248.3 146-97.5.4-187.8-70-253.6-146z" id="path827" fill="none" stroke="#3B3838" stroke-width="26" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10"  />
 
 <ellipse cx="294" cy="460" rx="270" ry="25" fill="#3B3838"  />

</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @kiskiskit всегда, пожалуйста

Comment: Александр перешел на JS, это знаковый день!)))

Answer (score 3):

Конечно не pixel perfect, но поигравшись в цифрами можно приблизится.

```css
:root {
  --size: 200px;
  --border: 20px;
}

.eye {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  border: var(--border) solid black;
  border-radius: 80% 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.eyeball {
  position: absolute;
  border: var(--border) solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  top: -35%;
  left: -35%;
}

.pupil {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  width: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  background: #feb702;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  <div class="eyeball">
    <div class="pupil"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Upd:

```js
const eyeball = document.querySelector('#eyeball');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

let cursor = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let position = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

let width = 500;
let height = 500;
let radius = 40;
let speedMultiplier = 1e-3;
let lastTime;
let frames = 5e5;

function onMouseMove(event) {
  const bounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  cursor.x = event.clientX - bounds.left - bounds.width / 2;
  cursor.y = event.clientY - bounds.top - bounds.height / 2;
  cursor.length = Math.sqrt(cursor.x * cursor.x + cursor.y * cursor.y);
  cursor.x *= radius / cursor.length;
  cursor.y *= radius / cursor.length;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

function loop(timestamp) {
  const deltaTime = lastTime ? timestamp - lastTime : 0;
  lastTime = timestamp;
  if (deltaTime === 0 && --frames > 0) {
    return requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  if (deltaTime === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const multiplier = speedMultiplier * deltaTime;

  const vector = {
    x: cursor.x - position.x,
    y: cursor.y - position.y,
  };

  position.x += vector.x * multiplier;
  position.y += vector.y * multiplier;


  eyeball.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${position.x}, ${position.y})`);

  if (--frames > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 5;
        }
        .st1 {
            fill: #feb702;
            stroke: none;
        }
    </style>
    <mask id="eyemask">
        <rect fill="black" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        <path stroke="black" fill="white" d="m 14,50 c 28,27 43,28 72,0 -28,-27 -44,-27 -72,0 z" />
    </mask>
    <path class="st0" d="m 10,50 c 30,30 50,30 80,0 -30,-30 -50,-30 -80,0 z" />
    <g mask="url(#eyemask)">
      <g id="eyeball">
        <circle class="st0" cx="50" cy="40" r="23" />
        <circle class="st1" cx="50" cy="40" r="10" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: svg был бы норм вариант

Comment: Согласен, но svg нет в тегах и в вопросе.

Comment: @UserTest013 я даже не подумал про svg. не подскажите, как можно сделать с svg с сохранением анимации?

Comment: @kiskiskit, извините, но svg и анимации - это уже другой вопрос. То что вы добавили в теги svg уже не изменит моего ответа :)

Comment: @UserTest013 хорошо, понял вас. спасибо большое

Comment: @UserTest013 у меня частично получилось реализовать анимацию с svg, но когда добавляю нижнюю линию, анимация перестаёт работать корректно, поэтому я решил добавить эту нижнюю линию с помощью div. подскажите пожалуйста, как можно грамотно оформить дивом эту нижнюю линию, чтобы она была в виде полукруга? 
ещё раз спасибо за помощь

Comment: отредактировал свой ответ